# Jetpack compose sets the cursor color of BasicTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm a beginner and I'm customizing a search box using `BasicTextField`.

```kotlin
  var search by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

  val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

  BasicTextField(
    value = search,
    onValueChange = { search = it },
    modifier = Modifier.border(0.dp, Color.Transparent),
    cursorBrush = SolidColor(Color.Red)
  ) {
    OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
        value = search,
        enabled = true,
        innerTextField = it,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        singleLine = true,
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
        colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(         
          cursorColor = Color.Red,
          errorCursorColor = Color.Red
        ),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(12.dp)
      )
  }
```

I found that what actually changes the cursor color is `BasicTextField#cursorBrush`, so what does `TextFieldColors#cursorColor` do? Or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cursorBrush` is from the `BasicTextField` object. The `cursorColor` though is within the `decorationBox` object. Since the cursor is not part of the box but the textfield, changing the `cursorColor` won't affect the `BasicTextField` properties.

(The `colors` property of the `decorationBox` is of type `TextFieldColors` that's why you see the `cursorColor` also there.)

Comment: So what is the scenario where `cursorColor` really works?

Comment: Any TextField that the properties change through the TextFieldColors. For instance `OutlinedTextField(colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(cursorColor = Color.Red), ...)` does change the cursor color.